# Why account for the friction coefficient in the normal force for a motorcycle on a wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A motorbike drives around a vertical cylinder. The friction coefficient $\mu_0$ is given, along with the radius $r$ of the cylinder. The aim is to calculate the minimal velocity of the motorbike, so that it doesn't fall down.

I understand that $F_N=F_{cp}$ and $F_R\leq \mu_0 F_N$. However, to calculate the velocity, the formula $\mu_0 F_N=mg$ is used. Why do we need to account for the friction with the normal/ centripetal force? I know that there must be friction, I just don't understand why it has to be accounted for in that place.

Is it because the friction force points upwards? If so, don't we need to account for the component part pointing "backwards", seeing as the motorbike is driving forwards?

Comment: its not. clear to me what you mean by "driving around a vertical cylinder"?

Comment: Also, in circular motion we are normally interested in the maximum speed before skidding (loss of traction)  occurs, not minimum speed. So why the interest in minimum speed? Does this involve leaning into the turn? Clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...don't we need to account for the component [of friction] pointing "backwards," , seeing as the motorbike is driving forwards?

There is no "backwards" component if the motorbike is cruising around the wall at a constant rate. Or, more accurately, there is a *small* backward component—just enough to balance the wind resistance that the bike feels—but I'm *guessing* that for the purpose of this exercise you are allowed to pretend that there is no wind resistance. Without wind resistance, there's nothing to slow the bike's forward progress, so there's no need of friction to keep it rolling along. We only care about the vertical component that's needed to balance the $mg$ force that wants to pull the bike down to the floor.